# Create a xml root element for a clob which does not have a root element in Oracle

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

By iteration over a cursor I create a CLOB which has below xml format. Suppose `l_tot_clob` clob contains the below:

```
<a row="1">
 <b>test</b>
<a>
<a row="2">
 <b>test</b>
</a>
```

Then I try to put above inside another element root called Record and assign the result to a another clob called `l_return_clob`. The code for that is below:

```
SELECT xmlelement("Record" , xmlconcat(xmltype(l_tot_clob))).getclobval() 
INTO l_return_clob
FROM dual;
```

What I am expecting from the retrun `l_return_clob` is something as this:

```
<Record>
<a row="1">
 <b>test</b>
<a>
<a row="2">
 <b>test</b>
</a>
</Record>
```

But as I assume since the `l_tot_clob` does not have a parent element so at the point I try to create a root element as Record, it gives the below error:

> fdm_ttwof_pkg.main_prc - Exception -ORA-31011: XML parsing failed
>   ORA-19202: Error occurred in XML processing LPX-00245: extra data
>   after end of document

How can I add the Record element as the root element in this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all you need is just to enclose your xml in `<Record>..</Record>`, and your XML is in CLOB, then why don't you just simply concatenate the `'<Record>'` and `'</Record>'` strings?

```
DECLARE
  v_clob CLOB;
  v_clob_with_root CLOB;
  v_xml xmltype;
BEGIN
  v_clob := '
    <a row="1">
     <b>test</b>
    <a>
    <a row="2">
     <b>test</b>
    </a>';

  v_clob_with_root := '<Record>' || v_clob_with_root || '</Record>';

  v_xml := xmltype(v_clob_with_root); -- no errors, XML is correct
END;
```