# How to solve complex XMLELEMENT in Oracle

Tags: xml, plsql, oracle11g

problem

XML

```
<logs>
    <log>
        <ID>123456</ID>
        <NAME>TEST</NAME>
    </log>
</logs>
<logs>
    <log>
        <ID>1234567</ID>
        <NAME>TEST1</NAME>
    </log>
</logs>
```

in the above xml logs are closing just after log tag.

But i need XML where logs tag to closed in xml in given below.

```
<logs>
    <log>
        <ID>123456</ID>
        <NAME>TEST</NAME>
    </log>
    <log>
        <ID>1234567</ID>
        <NAME>TEST1</NAME>
    </log>
</logs>
```

code i tried

v_output is output variable of clob type.

```
BEGIN
    x := XMLType (in_xml);

    FOR r IN (SELECT EXTRACTVALUE (VALUE (p), '/log/id/text()') AS log_id
                FROM TABLE (XMLSEQUENCE (EXTRACT (x, '/logs/log'))) p)
    LOOP
        OPEN cursorname (r.id);

        FETCH cursorname INTO tmp;

        -- fetching columns
        IF cursorname%FOUND
        THEN
            SELECT XMLELEMENT ("logs",
                               XMLELEMENT ("log", XMLFOREST (id, name))).GETCLOBVAL ()
              INTO out_xml
              FROM  view where id in ( rec1.id ) ;

            v_output := out_xml;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE (v_output);
        END IF;

        CLOSE cursorname;
    END LOOP;
```

- can anyone suggest how can i solve multiple xml elements using xmlelement.
- Input is XML and after parsing xml output should be xml.
- if i have requirement Dyanamic XML i could use code below.

  ```
  select xmltype(cursor(select * from view )) from dual;
  ```
- cursor is in loop.
- Any suggestion is most welcome.

Comment: The first 'XML' isn't valid and can't be treated as an XMLType, so it's slightly unclear what you are showing us - if that is your current output then what is the input (`in_xml`)? Or where do the ID and name values come from? And what is `view`? What is `cursorname`?

Comment: do no bother about xml validation please can give solution

Comment: I can't give you a solution if I don't understand your problem, the initial data and what you're trying to do.

Comment: in_xml   <logs>
    <log>
        <ID>123456</ID>
        
    </log>
    <log>
        <ID>1234567</ID>
      
    </log>
</logs>

Comment: im trying to get details by accessing id and  using cursor fetch data by id

Comment: OK, so the incoming XML just has IDs, and you essentially need to modify it to include the corresponding name which you get from your view? What if there is no matching row in the view, or will there always be?

Comment: i tried code    v_clob_with_root := '<logs>' || out_xml || '</logs>';

  v_output := v_clob_with_root;

Comment: My Question is similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763224/create-a-xml-root-element-for-a-clob-which-does-not-have-a-root-element-in-oracl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand what you're trying to do, you're starting from an string version of an XML document like:

```
<logs><log><ID>123456</ID></log><log><ID>1234567</ID></log></logs>
```

and trying to add the `name` value corresponding to each of those `id` value, which you get from a view.

You could extract all the IDs using an XMLTable, join those to the view, and reconstruct the final XML via XMLAgg, something like:

```
select xmlelement("logs", xmlagg(xmlelement("log", xmlforest(v.id, v.name)))).getclobval()
into out_xml
from xmltable(
  '/logs/log'
  passing xmltype(in_xml)
  columns id number path 'ID'
) x
join your_view v on v.id = x.id;
```

As a demo in plain SQL starting from your string, and with a CTE to represent your view:

```
-- CTE to represent your view
with your_view (id, name) as (
  select 123456, 'TEST' from dual
  union all
  select 1234567, 'TEST1' from dual
)
-- actual query
select xmlelement("logs", xmlagg(xmlelement("log", xmlforest(v.id, v.name)))).getclobval()
from xmltable(
  '/logs/log'
  passing xmltype('<logs><log><ID>123456</ID></log><log><ID>1234567</ID></log></logs>')
  columns id number path 'ID'
) x
join your_view v on v.id = x.id;

XMLELEMENT("LOGS",XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT("LOG",XMLFOREST(V.ID,V.NAME)))).GETCLOBVAL()                     
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<logs><log><ID>123456</ID><NAME>TEST</NAME></log><log><ID>1234567</ID><NAME>TEST1</NAME></log></logs>
```

or serialized to prettify it:

```
-- CTE to represent your view
with your_view (id, name) as (
  select 123456, 'TEST' from dual
  union all
  select 1234567, 'TEST1' from dual
)
-- actual query
select xmlserialize(document
  xmlelement("logs", xmlagg(xmlelement("log", xmlforest(v.id, v.name))))
  indent) as out_xml
from xmltable(
  '/logs/log'
  passing xmltype('<logs><log><ID>123456</ID></log><log><ID>1234567</ID></log></logs>')
  columns id number path 'ID'
) x
join your_view v on v.id = x.id;

OUT_XML                                                                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<logs>
  <log>
    <ID>123456</ID>
    <NAME>TEST</NAME>
  </log>
  <log>
    <ID>1234567</ID>
    <NAME>TEST1</NAME>
  </log>
</logs>
```

---

If you really wanted to use the mechanism shown in the question you linked to then you could build up the final output CLOB by appending each element generated inside the loop, with the start and end `logs` tag added outside the loop:

```
declare
  in_xml clob := '<logs><log><ID>123456</ID></log><log><ID>1234567</ID></log></logs>';
  out_xml clob;
  v_output clob;
begin
  v_output := '<logs>';
  for r in (
    select id
    from xmltable(
      '/logs/log'
      passing xmltype(in_xml)
      columns id number path 'ID'
    )
  )
  loop
     select xmlelement("log", xmlforest (id, name)).getclobval()
     into out_xml
     from your_view where id = r.id;

     v_output := v_output || out_xml;
  end loop;
  v_output := v_output || '</logs>';
  dbms_output.put_line (v_output);
end;
/

<logs><log><ID>123456</ID><NAME>TEST</NAME></log><log><ID>1234567</ID><NAME>TEST1</NAME></log></logs>


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

But it's simpler to avoid the cursor loop and just join once:

```
declare
  in_xml clob := '<logs><log><ID>123456</ID></log><log><ID>1234567</ID></log></logs>';
  v_output clob;
begin
  select xmlelement("logs", xmlagg(xmlelement("log", xmlforest(v.id, v.name)))).getclobval()
  into v_output
  from xmltable(
    '/logs/log'
    passing xmltype(in_xml)
    columns id number path 'ID'
  ) x
  join your_view v on v.id = x.id;

  dbms_output.put_line (v_output);
end;
/

<logs><log><ID>123456</ID><NAME>TEST</NAME></log><log><ID>1234567</ID><NAME>TEST1</NAME></log></logs>


PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Comment: My Question is related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19763224/create-a-xml-root-element-for-a-clob-which-does-not-have-a-root-element-in-oracl

Comment: in input i were getting id in xml then i need to fetch records  on for example where id (1233,12344)   i have shown sample xml [id,name] in xml but there few more .

Comment: @afeef - well, only if you want to make your code more complicated and probably slower than it needs to be; you don't need to use loops or seperate queries against the view...

Comment: @afeef - if there are more elements that you need to include and they all come from the same view, then just add those column names to the `xmlforest()` call?

Comment: Many Thanks for the help i will try solution and let you know.

Comment: HI ALEX i tried code "But it's simpler to avoid the cursor loop and just join once:" output  anonymous block completed
<logs></logs>

Comment: That suggests there is no matching data in your view; or possibly that the node name in your input XML is `id` rather than `ID` - so the reference to `path 'ID`' would need to change to `path 'id'` to match. You've shown it as uppercase `ID` in the question and comments, but your original code suggests it is actually lowercase `id` (from the `'/log/id/text()'` part).